# Cannot figure out how to Pull data from a JSON url to an Angular Material Table

Tags: json, angular, parsing, angular-material

I currently have the Angular Material Table set up with data from a List.

I would like to populate this list with data from a JSON url.

I assume i would have to first parse the data in to the list, however i have tried numerous ways of doing this online and have had no joy. I have stripped my code down so that it has the current working table pulling infor from a hardcoded list.

Please can anyone advise on how i would do this.

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  title = 'UnitySLATable';

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['groups', 'areas', 'applications', 'regions', 'as_of_dates'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SLAList>(SLAS);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

}

export interface SLAList {
  groups: string;
  areas: string;
  applications: string;
  regions: string;
  as_of_dates: string;
}

const SLAS: SLAList[] = [
  {groups: 'test', areas: 'test', applications: 'test', regions: 'test', as_of_dates: 'test'},
];
```

app.component.html:

```
<body>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <span>Unity: Daily SLA Dashboard</span>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-toolbar>
      <button mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="home">Home</button>
      <mat-menu #home="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Overview</button>
      </mat-menu>

          <button mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="selfServ">Self Service</button>
      <mat-menu #selfServ="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>SLA Management</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>SLA Batch Update</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Permission Management</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Report Management</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>View Management</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Group Attribute Editor</button>
      </mat-menu>

          <button mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="legDash">Legacy Dashboards</button>
      <mat-menu #legDash="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Barclays Wealth</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Commodities</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Credit</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Operations and Cross Product Technology (OCPT)</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Enterprise Solutions</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Equities</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Fixed Income</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Reform</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Retail/Corporate Banking</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>FX</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>MIHBUS</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>MIHBUS Impact Analysis</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Options & Structured Rates</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Prime Services</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Risk & Analytics</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Sales</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Securitised Products</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>TWS</button>
      </mat-menu>

          <button mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="download">Download</button>
      <mat-menu #download="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>SLA Download</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Historical SLA Delivery</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Usage Report</button>
      </mat-menu>

          <button mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="support">Support</button>
      <mat-menu #support="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="documentation">Documentation</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Contacts</button>
      </mat-menu>

      <mat-menu #documentation="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Batch Update Template</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>SLA Template</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>User Guide</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>SLA Mass Upload/Download</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Wiki</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!-- Groups Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="groups">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Group </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.groups}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Areas Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="areas">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Area </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.areas}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Applications Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="applications">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Application </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.applications}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Regions Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="regions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Region </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.regions}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- AsOfDates Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="as_of_dates">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> As of </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.as_of_dates}} </td>
      </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>      
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</body>
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

So you actually just have to load your data and set it to the dataSource:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
```

In ngOnInit call your api (to get the Json) and assign your data to the table:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data ;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Hope this solves your Problem.